# How to check for the immediate following sibling of parents in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am now using xpath to test a node's parent node's immediate following sibling(uncle or ant) node.

My xml looks like

```
<MyParent>
 <A>
 <B>
 <C>
</MyParent>

<Uncle>
 ..
</Uncle>
```

Now I am in the template match for child node B, and I want to test if the immeididate following-sibling of my parent is called "Uncle",

I tried the following two xpaths:

```
<xsl:if test="parent::MyParent/following-sibling::*[1][self::Uncle]">
     <xsl:text>we have it</xsl:text>        
</xsl:if>
```

and

```
<xsl:if test="parent::MyParent[following-sibling::*[1][self::Uncle]]">
     <xsl:text>we have it</xsl:text>        
</xsl:if>
```

neither of them will work, could experts help debug where I made mistakes? Thanks :).

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Maybe it's not running in the context you think it is?  Perhaps you could share more of your script so we can check.

Comment: @_Robert: If your code doesn't produce the desired output, but the accepted answer does, this likely means that you have (default) namespace problems.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this.

```
../following-sibling::*[position()=1][name()='Uncle']
```